# C++ rounding errors

Tags: c++, floating-point, rounding-error

Given an array of integers, calculate the ratios of its elements that are positive, negative, and zero. Print the decimal value of each fraction on a new line with  places after the decimal.

Note: This challenge introduces precision problems. The test cases are scaled to six decimal places, though answers with absolute error of up to  are acceptable.

Example

There are n=5 elements, two positive, one negative, and two zeros. Results are printed as:

0.400000
0.200000
0.400000

I am writing my solution in c++, appropriate functions to process user input are given.

here is my function, but I keep getting test cases wrong I'm assuming due to rounding errors but I'm not sure how to fix this if anyone can provide some insight, would be greatly appreciated!

```
void plusMinus(vector<int> arr) {
    
    
    float pos, neg, zero, arrsize;
    arrsize = arr.size(); 
    
    for(int i=0; i< arr.size(); i++) {
        if(arr[i] == 0)
            zero++;
        if(arr[i] < 0)
            neg++;
        if(arr[i] > 0)
            pos++;
    }
    
    pos = pos/arrsize;
    neg = neg/arrsize;
    zero = zero/arrsize;
    

   cout << fixed << setprecision(6) << pos << endl;
    cout << fixed << setprecision(6) << neg << endl;
    cout << fixed << setprecision(6) << zero << endl;
}
```

Comment: your problem descripition seems to miss words. Eg "...though answers with absolute error of up to are acceptable." up to what?

Comment: please include input, output and expected output in the question

Comment: Please copy-paste the full and complete assignment text into your question.

Comment: Single-precision `float` is not a great type if you care about accuracy. Try `double` instead.

Comment: You are using uninitialised values for `pos`, `neg` and `zero`. That's Undefined Behaviour, your program can do absolutely anything it wants.

Comment: You did NOT initialize your values you should initialize your values. C++ will not do that for you e.g.. `float pos = 0.f`;

Comment: Unlike some other languages, variables of automatic storage duration in C++ (like `pos`, `neg` and `zero`) are, if not explicitly initialised, left uninitialised.   This means that accessing their values gives undefined behaviour, and their values are indeterminate.  To increment a variable (e.g. `pos++`) its original value must be accessed.  To fix, initialise the variables (e.g.  `float pos = 0.0f, neg = 0.0f, zero = 0.0f;`).  So your core problem is not one of rounding errors or precision (although fixing the problem of uninitialised variables, may expose other problems).

Comment: Do you have an upper bound on the size of the array? Is there any chance that it will overflow a float (which will happen at about 2^24)? In general use `double` by default and revert to `float` only if you have a good rationale for. BTW, passing your vector by value will result in an unneeded copy.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem that can cause this is that you are not initializing the variables.

In the below code, I have fixed this and a few other things:

```
void plusMinus(const vector<int> &arr)
{
    float pos = 0.f;
    float neg = 0.f;
    float zero = 0.f;
    float arrsize = arr.size();

    for(auto &i : arr)
    {
        if(i == 0)
            zero++;
        else if(i < 0)
            neg++;
        else if(i > 0)
            pos++;
    }

    pos = pos/arrsize;
    neg = neg/arrsize;
    zero = zero/arrsize;

    cout << fixed << setprecision(6);
    cout << pos << endl;
    cout << neg << endl;
    cout << zero << endl;
}
```